# Content in mac safari iframe is flickering on scroll when page kept open for some time

Tags: css, html, macos, safari

I have used material angular and angular js to develop a dashboard. When dashboard is opened in iframe, In most of the pages I found one issue in Mac safari browser that when a page kept open for some time(say 5-10min) then and tried to use that page then some elements in page goes up with scroll and other stays there only. This issue is not there in Chrome and other browser.

I have attached the link to gif which shows the issue.
[Link to gif](https://d3myyafggcycom.cloudfront.net/TESTING/assets/ezgif-3-64ee2c6f7b.gif)

Comment: @upvoters why ?

Comment: What is your question? Did you try to narrow down a case to identify what may cause your issue? How could we help you?

Comment: Without seeing any code or any other details outside of your description, I don't see how anyone can help (aside from guessing). And agreed on the upvotes: I don't know why you're getting upvoted for a vague question (which, as written, is off-topic as "why isn't this working").